# Splitting a string on a special character in a pandas dataframe column based on a conditional

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am trying to establish conformity in an address column in my pandas dataframe. I have a ZipCode Column that has two formats: 1) 87301 2) 87301-1234. Not every row has the hyphen so I need to split on the hyphen when it is present.

My data looks like this:

```
State  ZIP
CA     85145-7045
PA     76913
```

I have tried a few methods of tackling this problem. I have tried:

```
data['Zip_1'],data['Zip_2'] = data['Zip'].str.split('-').str
```

I have tried:

```
data['Zip'] = data['Zip'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)
data['Zip'] = data['Zip'][0]
data['Zip_drop'] = data['Zip'][1]
```

I have also tried using a lambda function.

However it just returns nulls.

I would expect the new column to return NaN for zipcodes that do not have the hyphen and the numbers after the hyphen if it does contain the hyphen. 
However, the new column just populates NaN for every observation

Comment: `splitsville = data['Zip'][data['Zip].str.contains("-")].str.split("-")`

Comment: ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values. It's right along the lines of what I am looking for so thank you for trying

Comment: @connerleavitt See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316346/numpy-select-returning-boolean-error-message/57316407#57316407. The `.str` methods act on object columns, which can hold anything, so their default is to return `NaN` when they act on a non string value. You should explicitly check `== True` or `.fillna(False)` when using them to slice a DataFrame

Comment: @ALollz great point and I had done that prior to asking the question. Thank you for verifying!

Comment: actually, better yet, you can specify `na=False` as an argument :D

Comment: You actually want your solution to keep the optional ZIP+4 digits, right, not drop or replace them? Don't call that optional second column `data['Zip_drop']` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using "**replace**" combined with **regular expressions**.

**Step 1**

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['CA', 'PA'],
                           'ZIP': ['85145-7045', '76913'] })

example_df
```

[image]

**Step 2**

```
# Keep only the numbers before the hyphen (if any).
example_df = example_df.replace('\-\d*', '', regex=True)
example_df
```

[image: output]

Comment: The OP wanted to keep the optional ZIP+4 digits, not drop them.

Answer (score 0):

Get a dataframe of all zipcodes containing a hyphen, and place it in a new column

```
data['Zip Hyphen'] = data['Zip'].str.find('-')
```

Then, from the dataframe with column Zip, drop any rows where there is a hyphen contained

```
 data = data.drop(data[data['Zip'].str.find('-')].index)
```

EDIT:
This code is not tested but the general idea is there

Comment: Not a bad idea, although I would like to retain the observations with hyphens, but get ride of the hyphen and numbers that follow it