# How to avoid NaN when using np.where function in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe like this,

```
col1    col2   col3
1       apple   a,b 
2       car      c
3       dog     a,c
4       dog     NaN
```

I tried to create three new columns, `a`,`b` and `c`, which give '1' if it contains a specific string, otherwise, '0'.

```
df['a']= np.where(df['col3'].str.contains('a'),1,0)
df['b']= np.where(df['col3'].str.contains('b'),1,0)
df['c']= np.where(df['col3'].str.contains('c'),1,0)
```

But it seems NaN values were not handled correctly. It gives me a result like,

```
col1  col2  col3    a   b   c
1    apple   a,b    1   1   0
2     car     c     0   0   1
3     dog    a,c    1   0   1
4     dog    NaN    1   1   1
```

It should be all '0's in the 4th row. How can I change my code to get the right answer?

Comment: Why not drop NaN before using np.where function like df = df.dropna()

Comment: @Kapil that's one possibility, but it seems OP wants to keep frame structure and append the parsed columns back, which wouldn't work if a `dropna` was done first.

Comment: Use `df.join(df['col2'].str.get_dummies(','))`

Comment: You clearly need `get_dummies`, but for the sake of your question, `NaN`s are `True` values, so don't trust numpy judgement on that - explicitly fill at the end to avoid ambiguity: `df.col2.str.contains('a').fillna(False)`

Comment: The reason why `NaN`s are True can be found [on the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) - you have very limited number of objects which are cast to `False`, and all rest is `True`

Comment: There's a duplicate somewhere, let me find it. But there's specifically an argument for this. Specify `na=False`

Comment: Is this what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316346/numpy-select-returning-boolean-error-message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I will do

```
s=df.col2.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
Out[29]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  1  0
1  0  0  1
2  1  0  1
3  0  0  0
df=pd.concat([df,s],axis=1)
```

Comment: Both this and user3483203's comment are great, but if the column is not delimited and actually a `str.contains` is required then it wouldn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fillna(False)`. 
You are using Boolean indexing so always the values ​​corresponding to NaN will be 0

```
df['a']= np.where(df['col2'].str.contains('a').fillna(False),1,0)
df['b']= np.where(df['col2'].str.contains('b').fillna(False),1,0)
df['c']= np.where(df['col2'].str.contains('c').fillna(False),1,0)
```

Output:

```
   col1   col2 col3  a  b  c
0     1  apple  a,b  1  0  0
1     2    car    c  1  0  1
2     3    dog  a,c  0  0  0
3     4    dog  NaN  0  0  0
```